# Create managable flowchart for documentation

Tags: open-source, charts

I would like to create a flowchart for complex codes (can be written in any language) and use it for documentation purposes. Do you know any open source solution?

The specifications I need are:

1. Flowchart generated from code (for instance XML) and not drawn by software (for instance Visio).
2. Being able to make a query from a complex flowchart (for instance find file name, variables etc.).
3. Being able to add/remove any part of code easily.
4. Being able to get different view for different usage (documentation, presentation).

Just to give you an idea what I am looking for: http://www.flowgorithm.org/ is very interesting, however the main problem is it is not open source.

Comment: Any particular operating system?

Comment: I think it's clear that you want to draw the flowcharts first, as part of design. You should also be aware that if you want to document existing code then there are programs which will auto-generate flowcharts from your code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22411136/automatic-flowchart-tool

Comment: If you want to draw your flowcharts in the browser, using JS, then see https://hackernoon.com/quick-text-based-flowcharts-for-developers-3c68c4728134

Comment: You simply cannot beat PlantUML for drawing UML from text. Flowcharts are not part of UMl, but this shows a simple flowchart as an activity diagram : http://forum.plantuml.net/4438/how-to-flowchart-a-or-b-in-activity-diagram

Answer (score 1):

Well, my go to when I want to draw anything at all from text input is [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/). See [this page](https://www.graphviz.org/gallery/) for samples for what it can do.

I was surprised not to see a flowchart in the gallery, but a quick Google found [this page](http://melp.nl/2013/08/flow-charts-in-code-enter-graphviz-and-the-dot-language/), which shows this code

```
digraph {
    label="How to make sure 'input' is valid"

    start[shape="box", style=rounded];
    end[shape="box", style=rounded];
    if_valid[shape="diamond", style=""];
    message[shape="parallelogram", style=""]
    input[shape="parallelogram", style=""]

    start -> input;
    input -> if_valid;
    if_valid -> message[label="no"];
    if_valid -> end[label="yes"];
    message -> input;
}
```

generating this diagram

[image]

is that good enough? If not, please give more info & we will try to help further. This is a very interesting question & I have starred it as favo(u)rite. I love generating diagrams, Message Sequence Charts, State/Event charts, etc from plain ascii text.

Comment: IIRC, you can embed such diagrams into DoxyGen comments, just by giving the input text.

Comment: There is a free web-based Graphviz editor at http://sandbox.kidstrythisathome.com/erdos/

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814621/is-there-any-good-ide-or-wysiwyg-editor-for-graphviz

Comment: And my new question https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/47442/gratis-ide-editor-for-graphviz