# Gratis IDE/editor for Graphviz

Tags: windows, gratis, ide, editor, graphviz

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814621/is-there-any-good-ide-or-wysiwyg-editor-for-graphviz), but it is eight years old, and asking for an OS X app.

Is there any [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) IDE/editor where I can edit my input text, split-screen, and immediately have the [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/) diagram generated?

I would prefer a stand-alone program, but would also accept a plug-in for Eclipse or NotePad++.

Comment: Also look at this thread in the GraphViz forum: [GraphViz code editor supporting instant preview and allow multiple screen](https://forum.graphviz.org/t/graphviz-code-editor-supporting-instant-preview-and-allow-multiple-screen/915 "GraphViz code editor supporting instant preview and allow multiple screen - Dev - Graphviz")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I use [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) more often I found a beautiful extension ([Graphviz Interactive Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tintinweb.graphviz-interactive-preview)) that renders Graphviz *and* allows you to search nodes by name, select different rendering algorithms and trace edges originating/going into a node.

This is the plugin in action (taken from the VS Code Marketplace site):

> [image]

Comment: I did not want to award the answer for this excellent answer, because I did not want to take points away from the original answerer - then I saw that that was you :-)  So, all's well that ends well. This is the new accepted answer, and it looks excellent !! Thank you so much for updating after all this time. Have a 100 point bounty :-)

Comment: Bounty in 23 hours time. Sorry, the system forces it

Comment: That's very kind, thanks! I just keep finding better graphviz tooling, and am happy to point others to it as well.

Answer (score 3):

I found a Notepad++ plugin that works fairly well:

[NppGraphViz](https://github.com/jrebacz/NppGraphViz) by Github user [jrebacz](https://github.com/jrebacz/).

Combined with [this syntax highlighting scheme](https://github.com/signmotion/graphviz-syntax-highlighting) from [signmotion](https://github.com/signmotion) you get a nice editing environment in Notepad++:

[image]

Comment: As you can see by the answers I have posted to my own question, I have been looking for an answer to this for years now. Since I love using Notepad++ I am doubly greateful to have this answer. Installation was simple. Thanx a 1,000,000

Comment: I once found a plug in for MS Visual Studio, but have lost the link. Might be worth googlign for some, but I will be sticking with Notepad++

Comment: @Mawg Glad to be of help. I found your suggestion helpful as well, especially as you could browse different styles, which aids in learning Graphiz. Unfortunately the DotEditor has a bug that once you edit the script once, the preview does not respond to changes in the treeview anymore. This disrupted my work, so I looked and found something else (above plugin).

Comment: I love tools that take plain text as input, as I can generate the text from log files ,then run the tool. For instance, if you need Message Sequence Charts, you can't beat https://gitlab.com/msc-generator/msc-generator  Plus there are some good free UML tools

Answer (score 1):

I can say that [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com) editor (gratis) has plugin **External Tools**. Plugin allows to call GraphViz tool which generates picture, and you can press a hotkey to call this tool, eg F2. If this tool is fast, than it's ok for you.

How to setup CudaText:

- on Linux, configure the Python engine. Ie, write option `pylib__linux` into "user.json". See details in default.json: `Options / Settings-default` menu item.
- call menu `Plugins / Addon Manager / Install` and type there "Graphviz" to find lexer for Graphviz. Press Enter to install lexer.
- after restart of app, lexer Graphviz will be visible in Lexers menu.
- call menu `Plugins / Addon Manager / Install` and type "External tools" to find plugin "External Tools". Press Enter to install.
- after restart of app, you have Tools item in the top menu. Click it and configure new tool for Graphviz program. [Example tools - wiki info.](https://wiki.freepascal.org/CudaText#External_Tools)

Comment: Sounds good. I was hoping for an IDE which integrated, rather than launched, GraphViz, but if I don't find one, then this is the answer (or the same technique with NotePad++).

Comment: CudaText has good lexer for GraphViz_DOT too.

Comment: Then I will try it out (+1). But GraphViz is launched as an external tool? Correct?

Comment: Yes, GraphViz must be called as tool from plugin ExtTools.

Comment: Can you give specific instructions on how to get GraphViz working with CudaText - from the first time you ever run CudaText when nothing is configured?

Comment: @einpoklum Just added more info into my reply.

Answer (score 1):

I have just discovered https://vincenthee.github.io/DotEditor/ which does exactly what I asked for. I highly recommend it

Comment: Couldn't get it to work on Linux. Could you expand on how to get it working?

Comment: Hmmm, "`Linux 64bit  DotEditor-0.3.1-linux  Tested on Ubuntu 14.04, Arch Linux`" ... last tested five years ago :-( I can only suggest that you contact the programmer, or try running the Windows version under Wine. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

After my initial answer I found two other browser based options:

#### [Magjac's Graphiz Visual Editor](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/)

[image]

#### [Edotor](https://edotor.net/)

[image]

They both match all the requirements of the question asker:

- gratis
- edit input text
- split-screen
- immediately have the GraphViz diagram generated

I can't say one option is better than the other, it depends on what you need from a Graphviz IDE.
If you want to run them on your own machine or own network, both can be set-up with some effort, the [Graphviz Visual Editor](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/) even has a [Dockerfile available (in a pull request)](https://github.com/magjac/graphviz-visual-editor/pull/161/files).

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the feedback after all this time. Especially since I already awarded you the answer two years ago :-) I prefer non-browser based, in case I ever want to use it on proprietary or commercial data, but am fine with it for private use. I do like the idea of the Docker container. Thanks again !