# Windows software to make knowledge network graph?

Tags: windows, diagram, component-diagram

I need a tool that can run on Windows to draw this sketch:

[image]

**Requirements:**

- Have free form group (the dash group)
- Automatically rearrange the nodes for aesthetics when new nodes are added
- Export to images

Lucidchart and Dia don't have the first two features.

**Optional:**

- Sync with Android phones
- Free

Answer (score 3):

With a little learning you can do this with [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/) which is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Available for Windows, Linux & Mac
- Can produce images in a long list of formats
- Automatically re-lays out the image when items are added
- Missing is oval groups, (you can do rounded corners or dashed).

The code:

```
graph Inspirations {
    subgraph cluster_2 {
        style=dashed;
        shape=rounded;
        color=white;
        node [style=filled, color=lightgrey];
        gd [label="Google Docs"];
        gs [label="Google Search"];
        gi [label="Google Images"];
        gs -- gi;
        gs -- gd;
        color=black;
        label="Google"
    }
    w [label="Wikipedia"];
    se [label="Stack Exchange"];
    gs [label="Google Search"];
    se -- w;
    w -- gs;
    gs -- se;
}
```

Produced:
[image]

Comment: Does it have GUI? It seems best suited for LaTeX? How does it compare to Tikz?

Comment: You don't really need a GUI, since it will auto-arrange the layout (as you requested). But, you can take a look at the answer to [my question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/47442/gratis-ide-editor-for-graphviz)